# How to make my program ask for administrator privileges on execution

Tags: windows, winapi

I have searched and wondered how certain programs ask you to let them have administrator permissions when you start them up normally but haven't really found any good answer, I suppose they use something in Windows API but I haven't found anything that would help me.

Comment: `<trustInfo xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3'>
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='requireAdministrator'/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>` in manifest

Comment: @RichardCritten [`autoElevate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965735/6401656) this is another thing. but here need exactly `<requestedExecutionLevel level='requireAdministrator'/>`

Comment: Is there a way to add a manifest file to a DevC++ project?

Comment: different ways exist. maifest this is resourse. with `RT_MANIFEST` type and `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID` name for exe. so write manifest text file and include it in *.rc* as `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "my_manifest"`

Comment: Where `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID` is defined as 1, and `RT_MANIFEST` is defined as 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a manifest file into your `EXE` as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx